# Django translation redirect back to the current page

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization, translation

**How to redirect back to the current page.**
In my site I'm implementing two language which is 'en' and 'fa'
right now It's working but doesn't redirect to current page like docs.djangoproject.com we have instead it redirect me to home 'localhost:8000/fa/' or /en

here is the code:
for template hearders.py

```
<li class="dropdown default-dropdown">
    <form action="{% url 'selectlanguage' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
        <select name="language">
            {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
            {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for language in languages %}
                <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                    {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Go' %}">
    </form>
</li>
```

code for urls.py  is:

```
    path('selectlanguage', views.selectlanguage, name='selectlanguage'),
```

and for views.py is:

```
def selectlanguage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # check post
        cur_language = translation.get_language()
        lasturl= request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        lang = request.POST['language']
        translation.activate(lang)
        request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]=lang
        #return HttpResponse(lang)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(lang)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you cant use the built in language urls ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MichaelLindsay. actually it's my first time that I'm working with translation, is there any trick to implement such a system that i want? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

did you wrap the urls in the i18n_patterns?

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('about/', about_views.main, name='about'),
    path('news/', include(news_patterns, namespace='news')),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael Lindsay, yes I wrap the urls in the i18n_patterns. actually everything is working and I'm able to change the language but just it's not redirect me back to current page.

Comment: ahh, i see, I have end up using javascript to maniuplate the url. It's not django, but it avoids a get + redirect.